# How to add complex constraints in parse?

Tags: android, parse-platform, constraints

The Parse´s documentation explain how to add multiple constraints with an OR operator, with this example.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> lotsOfWins = ParseQuery.getQuery("Player");
    lotsOfWins.whereGreaterThan(150);

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> fewWins = ParseQuery.getQuery("Player");
    fewWins.whereLessThan(5);

    List<ParseQuery<ParseObject>> queries = new ArrayList<ParseQuery<ParseObject>>();
    queries.add(lotsOfWins);
    queries.add(fewWins);

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> mainQuery = ParseQuery.or(queries);
    mainQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
      public void done(List<ParseObject> results, ParseException e) {
        // results has the list of players that win a lot or haven't won much.
      }
    });
```

But I would like to add multiples OR´s operators, in a [Conjunctive normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form). To get somthing like this : (a OR b OR c)AND(d OR e OR f)AND(g OR h OR i)

There are any way to do this?

Comment: ps - noticed that you have no answers marked correct or upvoted in your history.  could be legit reasons, but you'll get better attention to your questions and help the site if you mark correct things that are correct and up-vote things that are helpful.  (both are done with the little controls near the big numeral at the upper left of the answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not sql, for sure, but ANDs are supported as compound conditions on the same query, and ORs using the Query.or method.  In other words, at the risk of being overly general, convert your logic to disjunctive form:

```
(a OR b) AND (c OR d) = (a AND c) OR (b AND c) OR (a AND d) OR (b AND d)
```

and build queries for each disjunction operand, each with multiple conjunction operands applied to it.

**EDIT** - regarding a very large disjunction, I don't find anyplace in the docs a limit to the number of query operands allowed by OR, but it makes sense that there would be a limit and that parse would keep it small.

When you've exhausted the query.or limit, you can implement a disjunction by running batches serially and summing the results.  In other words, group the queries into 10 or whatever, run them in succession with OR, for each add the results to a cumulative set that excludes duplicates.

But no matter how you slice it, the very complex condition will cause computational expense that will at some point run up against resource limits (some artificial based on what pay tier you're on) at parse.

For example, say you start with the predicate above and you've transformed it to disjunctive form as I have.  Say, also that Query.or is limited to only 2 queries.  You could still perform two or's serially and sum the results like this (in js):

```
var queryAC = new Parse.Query("MyClass");
// set queryAC.whereEqualTo(), where... for constraint a
// set queryAC.whereEqualTo(), where... for constraint c

var queryBC = new Parse.Query("MyClass");
// set queryAC.whereEqualTo(), where... for constraint b
// set queryAC.whereEqualTo(), where... for constraint c

var queryAD = new Parse.Query("MyClass");
// set queryAC.whereEqualTo(), where... for constraint a
// set queryAC.whereEqualTo(), where... for constraint d

var queryBD = new Parse.Query("MyClass");
// set queryAC.whereEqualTo(), where... for constraint b
// set queryAC.whereEqualTo(), where... for constraint d

// now, run them as or, serially.  in JS using promises...
var cumulativeResults = [];
Parse.Query.or(queryAC, queryBC).then(function(results) {
    cumulativeResults = cumulativeResults.concat(results);
    return Parse.Query.or(queryAD, queryBD);

    // this is how to do it in js with promises, in Java, the 
    // equivalent idea is to run the next or in the completion
    // callback of the first one
}).then(function (results) {
    cumulativeResults = cumulativeResults.concat(results);
    // remove dups here based on objectId, or do it in the line
    // above when adding results.
    // now cumulativeResults contains the OR sum of the original expression
});
```

Regarding applying deMorgan's rules, parse handles the negatives symbolically, by providing negative counterparts, e.g. `whereEqualTo` can be negated with `whereNotEqualTo`.  I'm pretty sure these are NOT functionally complete...I have occasionally run into cases where I couldn't express what I need.  My approach at that point is to read as little as I can into memory and use app logic to apply logical tests from there.

Comment: The idea is good, but there is a strange problem: I can not add more than 10 queries to apply them OR operator. For example: `for(int i=0; i<12;i++){
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("ParseObject");
            try {
                query.whereContains("country", "france"); 
                ListQueries.add(query);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }` If I apply `mainQuery.or(ListQueries)` does not work

Comment: Interesting.   Pls see edit.  Next trick is to run batches serially, but you may be running up against resource limitations.

Comment: I do not understan what you mean. Parse doesn`t say nothing about OR limitations.

Comment: Right, the docs don't mention a limit, but you are finding that there is one.  (I'm not surprised to learn that there is a limit, and not surprised that parse docs don't mention it).  There's still a way forward.  Do you not understand my suggestion about running them serially?  I could illustrate in javascript.

Comment: Yes please, that could help me. Other thing that I have think is to use Morgan`s law, but there is a problem, I dont know how to apply a NOT operator in the search.